# Which data structure and design for choosing best set of integers

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I need to implement an algorithm that chooses best triple (set of three integers) from predefined possibilities. In details:

1. There is an enum class defined as follows:

   `enum class myEnum 
   {
        a6 = 0,
        a10,
        a14,
        a18,
        a119,
        a123,
        a127,
        a131,
        a135
   }`

These members can be combined in set of triples 
`{a6,a10,a14}, {a6, a14, a18}`. There are just 11 possible triples (because of condition which is not important here). 
I have to choose triple, do some calculations for each member of triple and considering additional condition choose the best triple.

Which data structure and design would be best for these 11 triples? One triple is 'in use', so should be excluded from calculation or the calculations can be done for each and then exclude it from the result (that does not matter):

`struct a6 
{
    int value;
};`

```
typeToChoose possibleTriples = {

{
    a6, a10, a14
    a6, a10, a18
    a6, a14, a18
    a10, a14, a18    
    a119, a123, a127
    a119, a123, a131
    a119, a127, a131
    a123, a127, a131
    a123, a127, a135
    a123, a131, a135
    a127, a131, a135
}
```

Let's say that `{a6, a10, a14}` is in use. Now I have to iterate through
`possibleTriples` calculate sum for field `value` of structures:
`int sumOfValues = a6.value + a10.value + a18.value;`

and choose minimum triple with the lowest sum. {a6, a10, a14} == {a14, a10, a6}

Comment: I recommend you provide a [mcve] of code that does what you want (however inefficiently) and ask for optimization advice. Make It Work THEN Make It Better.

Comment: Given the vagueness of the requirement, and  assuming { a, b, c } !== { a, c, d }, I'd just make a 729-element array/vector  and iterate it with your test

Comment: Have you though of `std::tuple<myEnum, myEnum, myEnum>`?

Comment: Yes, I have, but still wondering what should be the type of this predefined structure in order to traverse it efficiently. Just array of tuples?

Answer (score 1):

An answer to this can only be as vague as the question.
Generally, you start from the most basic approach:

```
struct Triple {
   myEnum first, second, third;
};
```

Now, depending on what you want to achieve, you add further abstractions, effectively promoting such a struct to a class by incorporating encapsulation (private members), a certain interface in order to manipulate the representation, algorithms, overloaded operators etc.